# Separar los números de una columna a partir de un punto en SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Mi consulta devuelve el siguiente dato:

```
|          Columna001      |
|--------------------------|
|001, 0, 049, 066, 094, 126|
```

Quiero que me devuelva de esta forma:

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|001    |0      |049    |066    |094    |126    |
```

Como partir a partir de una " ,".

Comment: Y cuál es la consulta?

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, ni en la pregunta ni en los comentarios. En ninguna parte. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Usa `SUBSTRING_INDEX(valor,separador,número)`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna001,',',1) AS Column1,SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna001,',',2) AS Column2,SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna001,',',3) AS Column3,SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna001,',',4) AS Column4,SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna001,',',5) AS Column5,SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna006,',',1) AS Column6 FROM table
```

Comment: @Elvis, segun la [docuemntación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) la función `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` si esta soportada en oracle, por tanto de esa forma debería funcionar.